# xml and xsd schemaloction

Tags: xml, xsd

i have try folder path , default namespace  everything but still i am getting error saying schemalocation  not define

ERROR
 Namespace prefix xsi for schemaLocation on menuItem is not defined

here is the code
 the xml document is also a coumpound xml document 
 menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on XML
   Tutorial 4
   Case Problem 2
   Chester's Restaurant oatmeal

   Author:   
   Date:   03/14/2017   

   Filename:         menu.xml
   Supporting Files: menu.css, menu.xsd, recipe.css, recipe.xsd
-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="menu.css" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="recipe.css" ?>

<men:menuItem 
      xml:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://example.com/chestershartland/menu/ns"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/chesterhartland/menu/ns menu.xsd"
>
   <men:itemName>Oatmeal Breakfast</men:itemName>
   <men:description>
   <![CDATA[Our oatmeal is served warm with fresh fruit, pecans, raisins,
      and 100% maple syrup. Available all day.
   ]]>
   </men:description>
   <men:price>6.95</men:price>
   <men:icon>&#9824;</men:icon>  
   <men:icon>&#9829;</men:icon>
   <rec:recipe xmlns:rec="http://example.com/chestershartland/recipe/ns"
              schemaLocation="http://example.com/chestershartland/recipe/ns recipe.xsd"
   >
      <rec:itemName>Oatmeal Breakfast</rec:itemName>
      <rec:ingredients>
         <rec:ingredient>1/3 c steel cut oats</rec:ingredient>
         <rec:ingredient>1-1/4 c water</rec:ingredient>
         <rec:ingredient>1/4 t salt</rec:ingredient>
      </rec:ingredients>
      <rec:directions>
      <![CDATA[Bring water to a boil. Add salt and oats, stir, and lower heat
         to lowest setting. Cover and let stand 2 hours.
      ]]>
      </rec:directions>
   </rec:recipe>

</men:menuItem>
```

menu.xsd
 this is a xsd document that is ref the recipe.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/chestershartland/menu/ns" 
      xmlns="http://example.com/chestershartland/menu/ns"
    xmlns:rec="http://example.com/chestershartland/recipe/ns"
>
    <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/chestershartland/recipe/ns"
    schemaLocation="http://example.com/chestershartland/recipe/ns recipe.xsd"/>


    <xs:element name="menuItem">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="itemName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
                <xs:element name="icon" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:element ref="rec:recipe"/>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  xml:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

to

```
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     ^^
```

to define the `xsi` namespace prefix properly.